# How to get or set UI region scale via bpy?

Tags: python, interface

In Blender there is a way to control a scale of each UI region by holding <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Middle Mouse Button</kbd> and dragging the mouse up and down while the mouse cursor is over the desired region:
[image][image]
**My question** is: which property in `bpy` represents an actual scale of the given region? Is it even related to the region? Can not find any relative attributes in `bpy.context.region`.

The usecase. I'm currently trying to implement auto line break in the UI, like it is [described here](https://b3d.interplanety.org/en/multiline-text-in-blender-interface-panels/), but the given example doesn't take into account region scale changes, so the text becomes cropped whenever the region scale becomes larger than the original value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible.

The Outliner has Data API mode where you can explore it:

[image]

No scale I'm afraid.

You can also find stuff like this using Autocomplete feature in Python console( <kbd>Tab</kbd> ):

[image]

Nothing related to scale there as well.

[There is also documentation](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Region.html)

Comment: Thank you! I just wonder if there is no way to obtain region scale at all or if it is represented somewhere else in the API. I mean, not all the regions can be scaled: Text Editor, Python Console and the most of the Panels are available for scaling and Outliner and Menus are not. I think this may mean that this scale property probably belongs not to the region class itself but to some other class, but I have no idea to which one.